# Understanding summation decreasing index

Tags: summation

I'me following some summation examples and I came to this situation
$$|4-4| + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |4\cdot0.1^n| = -4+4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 0.1^n$$

How do they get to the last result?
I thought that $|-4+4|=0$ and decreasing the index should become $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |4\cdot0.1^{n+1}|$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The $\lvert 4-4\rvert$ is a red herring. Ignore it. You add the term for $n = 0$ to the series, therefore you have to subtract it outside.

Comment: You can remove all the absolute values, since all the values are non-negative.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ok. Did not know that. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|4-4| = -4 + 4 = -4 + 4\cdot (0.1)^0$.

So $$|4-4|+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 4\cdot |0.1|^n = -4 + 4\cdot (0.1)^0 + 4\sum_{n=1}^\infty (0.1)^n = -4+4\sum_{n=0}^\infty (0.1)^n$$

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I now understand. Now just have to figure out that final result is equal to $-4+\frac{4}{1-0.1}$

Comment: That's just the general equation: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$ when $|x|<1$.

Comment: sweet. Many thanks :)